# Understand the producer and receiver in rabbitmq

Tags: express, rabbitmq

I am trying to use rabbitmq and express to build a web application. I am very confused about the producer and receiver.

The tutorial said

> Producing means nothing more than sending. A program that sends messages is a producer, Consuming has a similar meaning to receiving. A consumer is a program that mostly waits to receive message.

Is that mean the server should be both producer and receiver? Because the server needs to get the client's request and send a response to the client. If that's the case, why we need to run the 2 scripts (producer.js and receiver.js) separately?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question appears to be mixing two different conceptual models.

*"the server needs to get the client's request and send a response to the client"* - That, in a nutshell, is the "client-server" paradigm/architecture, as typically used by web applications, where the client is the browser ("show me this web page, please") and the web app is the server ("OK, here is that page you requested").

Rabbit supports a very different paradigm/architecture (messaging), where (typically) the producer generates messages as they naturally occur (not based on any request). Those messages sit in one or more queues, waiting to be consumed by whoever has subscribed to those queues (the consumers). The consumer does not typically send requests to the server; instead it periodically checks to see if there are any new messages on the queue - and then consumes them.

Which paradigm you use depends on the purpose of your web application. Your app may even use both paradigms.

---

**Update**

"*Could you please give an example that uses messaging paradigm? I couldn't imagine how a website works without request and response.*"

When you say "a web site" then I will assume you mean web pages displayed in a browser, provided by a web application running on a server. In that specific case, then, yes, the standard approach is the "client-server" model. There is typically no messaging involved. Messaging is not a good fit for that type of model. Client-server is a great model.

But imagine that "web application" which is sending those web pages to the browser. It is quite possible that the web application may *also* provide *additional* services, not accessed directly via web page requests. One such service may be messaging-based: The application produces messages - for example, notifications of events relevant to the application. And users can consume those messages.

A very crude example: Imagine an auction web site. You can log on to the site and see web pages where you can place bids to buy items.

But you may also want to receive messages (e.g. via texts) telling you when there have been new bids from other people, placed on specific items that you are interested in. You don't want to have to constantly refresh a web page to get the latest data; and you don't want to receive updates about every bid on every product. This is a better fit for a different type of client - not one which requests web pages, but one which consumes messages.

So, I also can't imagine a *web site* which uses messaging to provide web pages (although I bet someone somewhere has built that). But I can imagine a web-based application which serves web pages (client-server) and which maybe also produces messages. Or a web-based application which produces messages, and may not even have any web pages at all.

Your `producer.js` is a tiny example of a program which is only a message producer. Your `consumer.js` program is a tiny example of a program which is only a message consumer. And sitting in between them is the message broker program (Rabbit) which is where the queues exist, and where messages are sent (and retrieved).

Comment: Could you please give an example that uses messaging paradigm? I couldn't imagine how a website works without request and response.

Comment: I added some notes.